# ApplicationInsights request customDimensions

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is it possible to add values to the `customDimensions` property of records in `requests` in `ApplicationInsights`? How?

I've found that `logger.BeginScope` can add them to `traces` -- the value must be `Dictionary<string, object>` (Passing `Dictionary<string, string>` does not work.)

Adding the properties to `Activity.Current.AddTag` has no effect.

Nor does adding properties to `TelemetryClient.Properties`.
(This is deprecated but nobody seems to know what to do instead.)

Comment: What is the framework and version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a custom `ITelemetryInitializer` like this

```
    internal class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private static readonly string[] _Headers = new string[] { "Referer" /*sic */, "X-Forwarded-For", };
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public TelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry item)
        {
            ISupportProperties tcp = item as ISupportProperties;
            if (item == null || _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null) { return; }

            LogTags tags = new LogTags();

            tags.AddTag("BuildName", BuildNameAttribute.GetBuildName());
            tags.AddTag("Method", _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method);
            tags.AddTag("Host", _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value);
            // RequestPath is added automaticallt.
            tags.AddTags(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Where(z => _Headers.Contains(z.Key)).SelectMany(z => z.Value.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(z.Key, y))));
            tags.AddTags(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query.SelectMany(z => z.Value.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(z.Key, y))));
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType && _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form != null)
            {
                tags.AddTags(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Where(z => z.Key.ToLower().Contains("password")).SelectMany(z => z.Value.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(z.Key, y.Length > 21 ? y.Substring(0, 21) + "..." : y))));
                tags.AddTags(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Select(z => new KeyValuePair<string, string>("File", $"{z.ContentType} '{z.FileName}' {z.Length}")));
            }

            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
            {
                tags.AddTags(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Select(z => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(z.Type, z.Value)));
            }
            else
            {
                tags.AddTag("authentication", "none");
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> tag in tags.GetAllTags())
            {
                tcp.Properties[tag.Key] = tag.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
        public static ILoggingBuilder AddLogging(this ILoggingBuilder builder, bool isDevelopment)
        {
            builder.ClearProviders();

            Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
            //builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("key");
            //Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;

            if (isDevelopment)
            {
                builder.AddBetterConsoleFormatter();
                //builder.AddHttpRequestLogger(); // Just can't get this to work :(
                //builder.AddBetterConsoleLogger();  // The singleton doesn't work very well and I don't understand why correlation IDs are omitted/
                //builder.AddConsole();
                builder.AddDebug();
            }
            else
            {
                // Add ApplicationInsights
                builder.AddApplicationInsights();
                builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
                builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryInitializer>();
            }
```

The `IHttpContextAccessor` deals with all that nastyness -- I was surprised to find that this is a singleton rather than scoped.

It turns out that this is not called until late on in the request pipeline which means that the auth middleware has run and therefore the `.User` is populated.